# How to make a route and classes category/subcategory/detailpage/

Tags: routes, kohana

I just started with Kohana. I would like the following urlrouting.

```
www.domain.com/tv/ledtv/samung-pt1234/ 
domain / category / subcategory / details page /
```

How is the route in the bootstrap and the classes?

I hope someone has some tips!

```
Route::set('products', 'products(/<brand>(/<category>(/<subcategory>)))')
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'products',
            'action'     => 'index',
```

));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this domain: `www.domain.com/tv/ledtv/samung-pt1234/` (domain, category, subcategory, details) try this route:

```
Route::set('products', <category>(/<subcategory>(/<details>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'products',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this topic whta helped. http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/41616#Comment_41616